# Navigation Bar (bootstrap) not Showing

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css' %}" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar-default">
    <div class="container fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="stopNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'music:index' %}">Go praT!</a>
         </div>


     </div>

</nav>
```

The Navigation bar is not showing up while working with Static URL.
When I am using the following lines to include the script Everything is working fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you may be missing a '/' in `"{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"` as `"{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"`

Comment: does your static url generated address guide you to the correct file location. Try to check in console for the error